# Atualização PHP - CHART JS em tempo real

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Problema: Preciso fazer um gráfico chart.js atualizar em tempo real, porém, para isso estou tendo que atualizar os dados vindos do banco com um botão de refresh, eu necessito que assim que a página carregar os dados sejam atualizados a cada 30 segundos.

CÓDIGO ARQUIVO -> PHP (FAZ CONSULTA)

```
<?php include '../../Config/conexao.php'; include '../../Models/Grafico.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM energy"; $query = $con->prepare($sql); $query->execute();

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Portuguese_Brazil'); $semana = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("- 7 days"));

$retorno = array();

$graf = new Grafico;

$dataBox[] = $graf->buscaDados($semana, $query, $retorno);

echo json_encode($dataBox); ?>
```

CLASSE PHP CHAMADA NO ARQUIVO ACIMA

```
<?php

class Grafico 
{
    private $results;

    public function buscaDados($semana, $query, $retorno)
    {
        while ($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            if (date("d/m/Y", strtotime($results['DATA_REGISTRO'])) > $semana) 
            {
                $retorno['semanal'][strtoupper(utf8_encode(strftime("%a", strtotime($results['DATA_REGISTRO']))))]
                ["HORARIO"] = date("H", strtotime($results['DATA_REGISTRO']));

                $retorno['semanal'][strtoupper(utf8_encode(strftime("%a", strtotime($results['DATA_REGISTRO']))))]
                ["ENERGIA"] = $results["ENERGIA"];
            }
        }
        return $retorno;
    } 
}

?>
```

CÓDIGO ARQUIVO -> CHART JS COM REQUISIÇÃO $.GET()

```
$('document').ready(()=>{
    $.get("../Controllers/php/dashboard.php", function(dados, status) {

        var valores = JSON.parse(dados);

        var diasSemana = [];
        var consumoSemanaEnergia = [];
        var consumoSemanaEnergiaHorario = [];

        $.each(valores, function(key, value)
        {
            $.each(value, function(chavePeriodo, consumo){
                $.each(consumo, function(chaveEnergia, valor)
                {
                    if (chavePeriodo = 'semanal')
                    {
                        diasSemana.push(chaveEnergia);
                        consumoSemanaEnergia.push(valor.ENERGIA);
                        consumoSemanaEnergiaHorario.push(valor.HORARIO);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        grafico (diasSemana, consumoSemanaEnergia, consumoSemanaEnergiaHorario);
    });
});
```

O que eu faço nesse caso? Eu já tentei usar um setInterval(), porém as video-aulas só mostram com um input usando $(elemento).keyup e no meu caso, o usuário não faria nada, nenhuma ação, isso só seria por conta do servidor. Alguém tem alguma ideia? Uma ajuda? Uma sugestão?

Comment: É um problema um pouco mais complexo, a estrutura back end realTime, com uma linguagem reativa, seria perfeito.

Porém podia inicialmente utilizar uma função setinterval no javascript, para dispara o refresh a cada 30 segundos.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Mas como eu faria isso? Exemplo,: atualmente eu clico no botao, o submit chama o arquivo php, o php retorna o json_encode a partir daí o jquery entra para separar os valores em cada array, então.... como eu faço isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Amigão. Estou repondendo por aqui, porque não posso fazer comentários... Você já pesquisou sobre WebSockets? Tive que fazer algo parecido só que com angular e usei um cara chamado SignalR. Porém o backend foi eu que desenvolvi...então consegui fazer o que eu precisava. No seu caso o backend é seu?
Espero ter ajudado...

Comment: Não tinha chegado a pesquisar, mas pesquisei e funcionou, obrigado!!